# SQL Inner join 2 tables with multiple column conditions and update

Tags: sql, sql-update, inner-join

I am using this script, trying to join 2 tables with 3 conditions and update T1:

```
Update T1 set T1.Inci = T2.Inci 
ON T1.Brands = T2.Brands 
AND T1.Category= T2.Category
AND T1.Date = T2.Date
```

but I encounter:

`Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ON'`.

Can't figure it out why.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

```
UPDATE
    T1
SET
    T1.Inci = T2.Inci 
FROM
    T1
INNER JOIN
    T2
ON
    T1.Brands = T2.Brands
AND
    T1.Category= T2.Category
AND
    T1.Date = T2.Date
```

Comment: Does the `ON` and `AND` operators only verify equality? Could they do the equivalent of `if ((T1.Brands < T2.Brands) && (T1.Category > T2.Category))`?

Comment: If you use something like `>` or `<` you reduce the types on joins you can use. The equality operator works really well with hash joins, but the other operators don't. You could inadvertently land in a situation where your join costs `O(n^2)` time (nested loop join).

Answer (score 5):

You need to do

```
Update table_xpto
set column_xpto = x.xpto_New
    ,column2 = x.column2New
from table_xpto xpto
   inner join table_xptoNew xptoNew ON xpto.bla = xptoNew.Bla
where <clause where>
```

If you need a better answer, you can give us more information :)

Answer (score 3):

```
UPDATE T1,T2 
INNER JOIN T1 ON  T1.Brands = T2.Brands
SET 
T1.Inci = T2.Inci
WHERE
    T1.Category= T2.Category
AND
    T1.Date = T2.Date
```

Comment: Reader can understand it update with inner join . atleast syntax way .

Answer (score 0):

You should join T1 and T2 tables using sql joins in order to analyze from two tables.  Link for learn joins :  https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp